# Проблема с ботом дс

Tags: python, discord, бот

Код:

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
    if message.author == self.user:
        return

    if message.content == 'ping':
        await message.channel.send('pong')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run('token')
```

ошибка:
RuntimeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
16 intents.message_content = True
17 client = MyClient(intents=intents)
---> 18 client.run('token')

```
1 frames
/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py in run(main, debug)
     31     """
     32     if events._get_running_loop() is not None:
--->     33         raise RuntimeError(
     34             "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop")
     35 

RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

система google colab

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли отступы:

```py
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        if message.content == 'ping':
            await message.channel.send('pong')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run('token')
```

Comment: А решение проблемы в заголовке?

Comment: Спасибо за совет но это не то